# Why does iterm show vim's logo instead of neovim when a buffer is opened in iterm2?

Tags: neovim, font

I'm curious if anyone knows how/why the logo uses vim instead of neovim's logo. I'd love to dig into and learn how to fix it. I apologize for the size of the pictures but this is what I mean. You can clearly see iterm2 is able to recognize the pid as being nvim, but the logo used is vim's. Happy to elaborate if anyone has questions or has run into this before and needs more context.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) I'm not sure this question is really about Vim. Or in other terms I'm not sure the Vim/Neovim specialists are the best to help you. I fear you need to contact the iterm2 specialist for that question ;-)

Comment: You're correct. We can delete the thread if it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

There's a `graphic_icons.json` in under `~/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/Resources` where the the icons are defined.  There's also a bunch of .tiff files which this json file is providing context for. I've added the neovim logo as a tiff to this directory and adjusted the .json to allow for iTerm to display the correct logo when "nvim" is app that is running in the iTerm session.

Comment: As an aside I've opened an feature request on iterm2's gitlab to have neovim's logo officially added to the list because the compression makes the logo come in quite hilariously.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the feedback :-)